# Why are Grease Pencil Strokes converted to thin Lines?

Tags: animation, shortcut, grease-pencil, 2d

I was working on a small test animation within the 2d animation, but somehow hit a hotkey that I couldn't seem to find and fix it.

The image below shows how it looks after the accidental hotkey input.

[image: Gif for better reference]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with the random hotkey, still don't know what it was.

On the top right corner of the viewport are four icons which change the *Viewport Shading*.

Select the second or third icon on the top right corner of the viewport to change *Viewport Shading*

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is because the viewport is set for *Wireframe* shading mode.
The hotkey for this is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

On the top of the screen you can use the radius setting to set the width of the stroke.

[image]

To change the scale of the whole layer, use Strokes>Thickness scale.

[image]

Comment: I checked both of them, Nothing was changed. 
I updated the images into a gif to make it easier to specify.