# Grease pencil: Why are my lines turning thin

Tags: grease-pencil

I am having the same issue as this person here (you'll find a gif of what I mean): [Why are Grease Pencil Strokes converted to thin Lines?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144691/why-are-grease-pencil-strokes-converted-to-thin-lines) and I've tried changing displays and fiddling around with the stroke properties but I've had no luck. I believe this was caused from accidently pressing on some short cut :(

If you've encountered this problem please help!